# How to prove this family of sets is a subset of another family of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

let $\mathscr{A}$ = {$A_i$: i $\in\Bbb N$} be a family of sets and k,m be natural numbers with k $\le$ m. Prove that

$${\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty}A_i} \subseteq \bigcap_{I = k}^{m}A_i$$

i had this problem for homework and i tried it but I'm not sure if I'm correct and there are no answers in the book for this
here is my attempt

let x $\in{\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty}A_i}$

then x $\in$ A for every A $\in\mathscr{A}$

or ($\forall$i$\in$k)(x$\in$$A_i$)

so ($\forall$i$\in\Bbb N$)(x $\in$ $A_i$)

therefore

$${\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty}A_i} \subseteq \bigcap_{I = k}^{m}A_i$$

if you can guide me on this proof that would be great, at first i thought that since the first is an infinite intersection that it couldn't possibly be a subset of the second one and then i thought well maybe it is a null set but i don't really know what the family of sets consists of, any help would be greatly appreciated thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dimostration is wrong in some passages. More precisely you should invert the two propositions you made. You said $\forall i\in \{m,...,k\}, \ \ x \in A_i $ then $\forall i\in \
\mathbb{N} ,\ x \in A_i $ but that is not actually true. To show what you want you just need to show that $$ (x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^ \infty A_i) \Rightarrow( x \in \bigcap_{i=k}^m A_i) $$
This is true because if $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^ \infty A_i$ then $x \in A_i$ for every $i=k,k+1,...,m$ hence $x$ belongs to the intersection of these $m-k$ sets $\ \ \bigcap_{i=k}^m A_i$.

Comment: Thanks alot, now i get where i went wrong, thanks for your time